# How to read the whole response in PHP sockets programming?

Tags: networking, php, sockets

As we know we can only read a specific number of bytes from the response.
How to read the whole response in one socket_read function call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own read function that keeps calling `socket_read` until you have the 'whole response'. How you do that will depend on exactly what a 'whole response' is. (That's why PHP can't do it for you. It has no idea what you consider to be a 'whole response'. Only you do.)

Whatever protocol you are implementing will tell you how to tell if you've gotten a whole response. You have to actually implement that protocol.

Comment: I am implementing HTTP protocol so that ,the end of the response will be ' \r\n ' ;
In this case i should call socket_read for every couple of bytes until i reach the " \r\n " ..
Is that correct ?!

Comment: The end of the header will be marked with \r\n\r\n (in HTTP 1.0 and later). What version of HTTP are you trying to implement? And are you implementing the server side or the client side? (And are you sure you want to do this? HTTP is not a simple protocol.)

Comment: I am using HTTP 1.0 ...
And i am implementing the client side

Comment: For 1.0, you don't need to support chunked encoding. The end of the response header is marked by \r\n\r\n. The end of the response data is marked by receiving the number of bytes in the 'Content-Length' header, or the connection being closed if there is no such header.